# Rails 3 - how to make a crossing? (routing)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, routes

I created a controller **names**. I have a model that contains a names of boys and girls (gender=0 for boys, 1 for girls).
If I set to URL the address `localhost:3000/names`, so will be rendered the view `index.html.erb`. In this view is an overview of data that are stored in database.

I am trying to edit it - I want to have on the address `localhost:3000/names` a crossing - here will be 2 links - **BOYS** and **GIRLS**. And after click on one of these links I would like to go on the address `localhost:3000/names/girls` (or boys) and here I would like to have an overview of data from database...

I am newbie still and I don't know, how to realize it... mainly how to edit my `routes.rb` - I would like to ask you about a help, how to do it...

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

So you want a `names_controller` with actions `boys` and `girls`, and you want routes to those?

How about something like this:

```
resources(:names) do
  collection do
    get :boys
    get :girls
  end
end
```

[Routes collection is documented here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources/collection).